# USB Booting Ubuntu on a company laptop

Tags: ubuntu

I have been issued a company laptop, and with it access to its BIOS - which is password encrypyted (although I was openly given the password). I have an external hard drive with a persistent Ubuntu OS on it that I use for school. I was wondering if there was any way that my company could track what I do when using my own OS (the persistent Ubuntu 16).

Side Note: My manager has told me he does not mind if I use my own OS so this is not the question

Thanks for any input!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, your company cannot track what you do in an OS, which is in a drive that they do not have.

So, keep the drive to yourself, and don't store any personal data on the company's drive.

Comment: Thank you for the answer! Just for clarification, and to validate my original train of thought, this is because any supervision software would be loaded with _their_ OS, and in my case would never have a chance to begin running, correct?

Comment: Yes, you are correct.  Monitoring/supervision/spy software typically runs in the OS.  And, since your Ubuntu is YOURS, only you can spy on yourself.  If you're of a paranoid nature, see Edward Snowden's leaks, where in some documents, he describes spy hardware in some chipsets.  But, I doubt your company would use such hardware.  And, you can feel safe in your Linux environment.

Comment: Thank you very much jehad! I thumbed you up but apparently I'm a bit too nooby on this forum for it to do anything (yet) :/

Comment: That's alright, I dip in and out of here for fun, not for points.  :)  Good luck.